# Android encryption

Tags: java, android, security, cryptography

I am working on an android application, and I need to use encryption for one aspect of it. I am really indifferent to which algorithm I use (AES, DES, RSA, etc...). I am aware that Java has a crypto package, but I am not familiar with it at all. Can someone post an example on how to do an encrypt/decrypt function?

Comment: The algorithm depends a lot on the usage scenario. What is it you're protecting, from whom, where, why and how do you plan to do it? AES (symmetric cipher) and RSA (asymmetric) function very differently.

Comment: I am simply storing a username and password locally on the device. I have have an RSA implementation and used that for my purposes.

Comment: @Steven - I'm not sure RSA is the best system for that.

Comment: I suspect you want to store the username and password of a remote service and use it to access some service "transparently" ?

This would make sense to be protected with symmetric encryption (AES) but how will you secure the AES key? With a password derived key? With some system key (maybe Android provides something internal for such purposes)

Before rolling your own, make sure that Android does not provide a "keychain" or "password store" style service, that would take care of it for you.

Comment: For future readers, please check [this](https://github.com/ryan652/EasyCrypt/) library as implementing encryption/decryption securely with key derivation, encoding and multiple datatypes can get really complicated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `java AES` library has a flaw in it that allows, under the right circumstances, a listener to decrypt the packets sent. See [Padding Oracle Exploit Tool vs Apache MyFaces](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=euujmKDxmC4).

That being said check out this SO question [Java 256bit AES Encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992019/java-256bit-aes-encryption).

Bouncy Castle AES EXAMPLE stolen from: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Security/EncryptionanddecryptionwithAESECBPKCS7Padding.htm

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class MainClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());    
    byte[] input = "www.java2s.com".getBytes();
    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 
                 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 
                 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 
                 0x15, 0x16, 0x17 };

    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding", "BC");

    System.out.println(new String(input));

    // encryption pass
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

    byte[] cipherText = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(input.length)];
    int ctLength = cipher.update(input, 0, input.length, cipherText, 0);
    ctLength += cipher.doFinal(cipherText, ctLength);
    System.out.println(new String(cipherText));
    System.out.println(ctLength);

    // decryption pass
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] plainText = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(ctLength)];
    int ptLength = cipher.update(cipherText, 0, ctLength, plainText, 0);
    ptLength += cipher.doFinal(plainText, ptLength);
    System.out.println(new String(plainText));
    System.out.println(ptLength);
  }
}
```

Comment: Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider())

What does this do?

Comment: Security.addProvider lets java know that you are planning on using a particular security provider (it basically installs that security provider into the security manager, similar to loading a library).

Comment: I just had what I'll assume is the weirdest coincidence ever: I watched the linked youtube video, and after each byte in the top row was decrypted (right to left) my computer rebooted. When I checked the system log, it was due to CPU temp above threshold. When I opened my computer to switch thermal putty with artic silver 5, I saw that the heatsink fan on the video card was burnt (literally brown, bubbly, and warped). I can't help but be paranoid that there's some faulty flash software exploit..

Comment: @snapfractalpop - I think you got the "snowcrash" virus.

Comment: I just looked that up and read about it..did I just infect my mind?

Comment: It's 6 1/2 year later... is this flaw still present?

Answer (score 1):

Look at my answer here [Android database encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203987/android-database-encryption/20179803#20179803). It contains 2 files that you can include in any of your applications that require data storage to be encrypted.

Comment: I going to test It tomorrow. It's look very interesting. Thanks bro.

Answer (score 1):

I would also check out Conceal to see if it fits your bill. It has a easy to use API which abstracts the cryptographic details: https://github.com/facebook/conceal/

Answer (score 0):

Considering the overhead to encrypt and decrypt data in Android, I devised a library that relies only in Android and Java native libraries to make the process as simple as possible.

To install, use the jcenter distribuition center.
On gradle:

`compile 'com.tinmegali.android:mcipher:0.4'`

**Usage**

```
String ALIAS = "alias"
MEncryptor encryptor = new MEncryptorBuilder( ALIAS ).build();
MDecryptor decryptor = new MDecryptorBuilder( ALIAS ).build();

String toEncrypt = "encrypt this string";
// encrypting
String encrypted = encryptor.encryptString( toEncrypt, this );

// decrypting
String decrypted = decryptor.decryptString( encrypted, this );
```

MCipher is compatible from SDK 19+, and it automatically adapts itself to smaller and large chunks of data. By default, it uses `AES/GCM/NoPadding` for SDKs 23+, and `RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding` for older versions.

[MCipher on Github](https://github.com/tinmegali/MCipher)