# Basic encryption on Android

Tags: android, encryption

I have seen the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150830/android-encryption). All well and good and I understand it, however it relies on the bounceycastle library for the provider. I don't want to bundle any additional third party libraries with my app if I can help it. I don't need fort knox style security, just some basic symmetric encryption for transmitting over the wire. How can I do basic encryption on Android with out third party libraries?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well BouncyCastle is included in Android, as you can see if you would try to include it you would get: `D/dalvikvm( 9268): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/bouncycastle/x509/extension/SubjectKeyIdentifierStructure;': multiple definitions` and so on.

However, not all algorithms are implemented - you would get an NoSuchAlgorithmException.
In Android 2.2 I found these to be implemented:

`PBEWITHSHAAND128BITAES-CBC-BC
PBEWITHSHAAND3-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC
1.2.840.113549.1.1.7
PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC
PBEWITHSHAAND192BITAES-CBC-BC
DESEDE
DES
1.2.840.113549.3.7
PBEWITHSHAAND2-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC
1.3.14.3.2.7
PBEWITHSHA256AND192BITAES-CBC-BC
PBEWITHSHAAND256BITAES-CBC-BC
PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC2-CBC
AES
2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.42
PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC
2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.22
2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.2`

Comment: I'm getting a shortbufferexception on the call to doFinal when encrypting (using the linked example) - any ideas?

Comment: Well, the example runs fine on my Nexus one, 2.2.
And you shouldn't get a shortbufferexception, but you can always try to set:

byte[] cipherText = new byte[2048];

To se if the encryption works, although you would get some junk in the printouts.

Comment: my cipherText is much larger than that - some 3800 bytes. Does the byte[].length need to be a multiple of 16?

Answer (score 5):

> I don't want to bundle any additional third party libraries with my app if I can help it.

You do not need third party libraries to use `javax.crypto`. There are online samples of using `javax.crypto`, such as [this](http://exampledepot.com/taxonomy/term/267) and [this](http://www.kodejava.org/browse/43.html). If you need a Base64 encoder, there is one in Android 2.2, or there are open source implementations available for that as well.

Comment: Do you know which crypto algorithms that Android BC supports? I know it is a crippled version of BC but can't find what it actually supports.

Comment: @metalideath: Off the top of my head, no. Also, somebody repackaged BC as org.spongycastle to get past the "crippled version" stuff, in case what you need is not available via the `javax.crypto` package.