# Android Encryption Supported Over IPSec

Tags: android, encryption, vpn

I'm exploring the various options that I have for connecting a device running `Android 2.2` to a VPN using IPSec, but I have been unable to find a comprehensive list of the encryption methods supported by the OS.

I have seen some description of the encryption methods supported by Android in general ([android-encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150830/android-encryption)), but I need information specific to IPSec.

Does anyone have this information or know where I might be able to find it?

Answer (score 1):

there's at least "aes-plain" available