# How to encrypt/decrypt images on android?

Tags: android, image, encryption

I have some experience developing basic android applications. However my professor demands that I implement Image encryption in android. I am very new to this concept - I googled the topic and I could understand some of it. I looked up in Stack Overflow for similar questions but couldn't find anything that helps me.

How do I begin with Image encryption/decryption in android? I'm aware of encryption standards such as AES, RSA, etc.

Please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808399/android-aes-encryption-decryption-of-images

Comment: I did go through that link, and the link posted there. I couldn't understand anything. Is there any other link I might find helpful?

Comment: First learn how to encrypt and decrypt some simple text: "This is a secret message."  Use AES in CBC mode with PKCS#7 padding.  RSA is not relevant to what your professor wants you to do.  Once you can do that, then move on to encrypting binary files.  Learn to walk before you run.