# Files internal to applications

Tags: android, file, memory, memory-management, sd-card

I read this sentence, form a book 
"Files: Files internal to applications, which you can store on a
removable storage medium"
and I am confused, well I expect that "Files internal to applications" saved from my app that will be accessible only from my app. and that is true when you save them internally in the phone memory.
But as the sentence says , you can save files to the sdcard also. And that is great but I think that everyone with 'external storage read' privilege set in the manifest will be able to read your file, so that doesn't make it internal to the app, it makes it publicly available to everyone.

My question is:
Is there any way to store the files in the 'removable storage medium' -> sdcard and those files to stay available only to my app, others application to be prevented from reading the content ?

I know that if you put files in data/data//files these files are only available to the app with that package name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
store the files in the 'removable storage medium' -> sdcard and those files to stay available only to my app
```

I don't think so, For `sdcard` it is not possible.

The one way is `store encrypted file` in sdcard and `key` for it is you can put (keep) in your application's `shared preference in private mode` and decrypt the file from your application when you want to read it.  But I think it some ugly way.

Comment: i think this is the only way to secure our data from another application.

Answer (score 1):

**It is possible** . For that you need to encrypt the data with some private key and write to SDCARD, when ever you want to process that data you have to decrypt it . `So another app can't access your data without decrypt it.`

[Android Encryption Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150830/android-encryption)