# Base64 Decode not working correctly along with Cipher.Decrypt in android

Tags: java, php, android, base64

Here's a string :

```
String msg="dpbqNszFN2cpmtlzPi3myV9M1ctlkSIQD95ue+T+9rz13T+Pe/aLZ8Pd5geI+PhEM/b0UeRS1cAzKybQsKICTBhh3ke5Jjw6BHWGESJWBnUT54lAlTvzkgOxpQ5stBh2cPPSn3KLyKmXifr8ClbV5s1k3Gy5C7HitA5KLw7hRxAmIGSWQG7PaiLNEVRbgicNfJ7Ic7VIdGA/UA51vK8mpywIR2YQUDPv30ThGq4DuclaJ3X4aVWVj8VYChcfM+82sViVU8HO3DF9CCU4EIADNET503olxiDZBp7WMYmJvWq0KhhZXkLSY3QFmcSMX6IThtdKKCcZp6hu3TtC+7aP7Q==";
```

So the byte array is

```
[1] => 100     [2] => 112     [3] => 98     [4] => 113     [5] => 78     [6] => 115     [7] => 122 ..
```

Which **should** be decoded to

[ I used PHP `base64_encode()` for encoding into the above form & `base64_decode()` for getting this output ]

```
[1] => 118     [2] => 150     [3] => 234     [4] => 54     [5] => 204     [6] => 197      7] => 55     ...
```

But the problem I'm facing is that ( In android , Using `Base64.decode(String)` ) it's getting decoded to  :

```
[118, -106, -22, 54, -52, -59, 55, 103, 41, -102, -39, 115, 62, 45, -26, -55, 95, 76, -43, -53, 101, -111, 34, 16, 15, -34, 110, 123, -28, -2, -10, -68, -11, -35, 63, -113, 123, -10, -117, 103, -61, -35, -26, 7, -120, -8, -8, 68, 51, -10, -12, 81, -28, 82, -43, -64, 51, 43, 38, -48, -80, -94, 2, 76, 24, 97, -34, 71, -71, 38, 60, 58, 4, 117, -122, 17, 34, 86, 6, 117, 19, -25, -119, 64, -107, 59, -13, -110, 3, -79, -91, 14, 108, -76, 24, 118, 112, -13, -46, -97, 114, -117, -56, -87, -105, -119, -6, -4, 10, 86, -43, -26, -51, 100, -36, 108, -71, 11, -79, -30, -76, 14, 74, 47, 14, -31, 71, 16, 38, 32, 100, -106, 64, 110, -49, 106, 34, -51, 17, 84, 91, -126, 39, 13, 124, -98, -56, 115, -75, 72, 116, 96, 63, 80, 14, 117, -68, -81, 38, -89, 44, 8, 71, 102, 16, 80, 51, -17, -33, 68, -31, 26, -82, 3, -71, -55, 90, 39, 117, -8, 105, 85, -107, -113, -59, 88, 10, 23, 31, 51, -17, 54, -79, 88, -107, 83, -63, -50, -36, 49, 125, 8, 37, 56, 16, -128, 3, 52, 68, -7, -45, 122, 37, -58, 32, -39, 6, -98, -42, 49, -119, -119, -67, 106, -76, 42, 24, 89, 94, 66, -46, 99, 116, 5, -103, -60, -116, 95, -94, 19, -122, -41, 74, 40, 39, 25, -89, -88, 110, -35, 59, 66, -5, -74, -113, -19]
```

As you can see , some  characters ( which are not readable though) , are not getting decoded correctly.
**Edit(2)** : bytes are signed in java and  unsigned in PHP . Thanks @Jon and @Tony for clearing that idea. But the bug remains in my code.

**Edit(1):**

Code Segment:

```
KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
BigInteger e=new BigInteger("65537");
BigInteger n=new BigInteger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
RSAPublicKeySpec keySpec=new RSAPublicKeySpec(n,e);
PublicKey pubKey = (PublicKey) fact.generatePublic(keySpec);
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pubKey );
String msg="dpbqNszFN2cpmtlzPi3myV9M1ctlkSIQD95ue+T+9rz13T+Pe/aLZ8Pd5geI+PhEM/b0UeRS1cAzKybQsKICTBhh3ke5Jjw6BHWGESJWBnUT54lAlTvzkgOxpQ5stBh2cPPSn3KLyKmXifr8ClbV5s1k3Gy5C7HitA5KLw7hRxAmIGSWQG7PaiLNEVRbgicNfJ7Ic7VIdGA/UA51vK8mpywIR2YQUDPv30ThGq4DuclaJ3X4aVWVj8VYChcfM+82sViVU8HO3DF9CCU4EIADNET503olxiDZBp7WMYmJvWq0KhhZXkLSY3QFmcSMX6IThtdKKCcZp6hu3TtC+7aP7Q==";
byte[] bytes=msg.getBytes("UTF-8");
byte[] enc_bytes= Base64.decode(bytes,Base64.DEFAULT);
byte[]  dt = cipher.doFinal(enc_bytes);   
String code=new String(dt,"UTF-8");
System.out.println(code);
```

Cipher decrypted String comes out as ( At the second system.out )

```
05-10 21:05:27.501: I/System.out(11809): �ќ2`��H&��'Va�x�m��0G�����V�T�����)^����/|���BG,f_r    fK�B7?�a��n������Jl�y�yL���}��΂Ճ������JZj�+�|�-#ș%u�1�z�c�G��nl�5����HELLO HI1 HI1 HI1 HI1 HI1 HI1 HI1 HI1 HI1 HI1 HI1 HI1 HI1 HI1 HI1 HI1 HI1 HI1 HI1 HI1 HI1 HI1 HI1 HI1 HI1 HI1 H
```

The Base64_encoded & signed data is "HELLO HI1 HI1 HI1 HI1 HI1 HI1 HI1 HI1 HI1 HI1 HI1 HI1 HI1 HI1 HI1 HI1 HI1 HI1 HI1 HI1 HI1 HI1 HI1 HI1 HI1 HI1 H"

---

**[Solved]**

Huge thanks to @JonSkeet .

`cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");` removed all the junk data prefixed to it.

Comment: Verify PHP uses the same algorithm as Android.

Comment: Base64 is universal. It should be. Right?.

Comment: I would not assume that. It would be easy enough to check.  But I think your issue is resolved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All looks fine to me - you just need to remember that bytes are signed in Java. So a value of -106 in Java corresponds to an unsigned value of 150. Once you bear that in mind, I think you'll see that all the values in PHP correspond to the values in Java.

Note that you ought to distinguish between *bytes* and *characters*. So when you say:

> As you can see , some characters ( which are not readable though) , are not getting decoded correctly.

You *actually* mean some bytes... and there's no such concept as a "readable" byte.

EDIT: I see no sign that you've actually *decrypted* the data at all.

You're converting the *still encrypted* result of the base64 decoding into text using the platform default encoding:

```
String tmpr=new String(baser);
```

You shouldn't be doing that - you should be using `baser` as the cipher-text to decrypt.

It's not at all clear where the `tmp` value you're passing to `doFinal` comes from at all...

Comment: What i meant was, the  Base64 encoded data is not a readable string. It is an encrypted data.

Comment: @ngen: If the problem is decryption (as you've added in a comment later) then that suggests the problem is with the encryption or decryption code, which you haven't shown us. The base64 part seems to be fine here. But it's important to understand that the decoded base64 isn't a *string* at all, readable or unreadable - it's just bytes.

Comment: Perhaps he means it was encrypted, then BASE-64'd?

Comment: @TonyEnnis: Yes, having seen another comment that makes sense. But it's still a mistake to talk about the decoded data as a "string" at all.

Comment: @Jon   , I've edited the question again. I've been at this for some hours in and out.  I have a string which is encrypted ( RSA ) and Base64'd the encrypted string ( Which is not readable by humans :-) ) .And then i passed it into the Android . But the bug occurs there.

Comment: @ngen: You're printing out something totally meaningless at the moment, and your code doesn't appear to be using the decoded base64 value for anything else. See my edit.

Comment: @JonSkeet  , I'm Sorry for being an idiot.   By hurrying up to add the code , I tried to make it readable  by editing it out of IDE. The original code has been added . Sorry again.

Comment: @ngen: Okay, so what encoding did you use in PHP before encryption? And how are you doing the encryption in the PHP code? And how are you setting up the decryption in the Java code? Just about the only bit of the pipeline we know *is* working is the base64 part...

Comment: @JonSkeet  Thanks for being patient in listening to this.  I'm using RSA-SHA1 . The data is in UTF-8 .   It is working as you can see from that `println()` .   The problem is that, the output data after the decryption its having garbage data.  I had two assumptions regarding that. 1) Cipher is having garbage data in its buffer. 2) The byte[] arrays signed nature .  And the  Android ( Encrypt) => PHP ( Decrypt) is working perfectly. Data is same on both sides.  But when it's done in the opposite direction, data is mangled with random characters in the beginning.

Comment: @ngen: Hang on - I thought you said you were *encrypting*. RSA-SHA1 is just a *signature*, not encryption. You can't decrypt a signature - it doesn't work that way. Please show *all* the code you're using, because at the moment it's not making much sense.

Comment: @JonSkeet  I'm not signing actually, I'm   encryting the data at one end and  decrypting it out of the encrypted code.   There is no signature and signature verification.

Comment: @JonSkeet  I'm very new (24 hours) to encrypting hence the confused terminologies used by me.  And i hit this bug some hours back. I can clean the output string somehow but i would like to know what's making it unclean in the first place. Hence spending time on it.

Comment: @ngen: Okay, I may have been confused by the SHA-1 part. What does your similar code for encryption (that works) do?

Comment: @ngen: No, that doesn't work for my way of working. But I would take base64 and PHP out of the equation completely: if you encrypt *and directly decrypt* in Java, does *that* work? I suspect you should actually try that and ask a separate question, as the basis of this question is base64, which I believe to be irrelevant here.

Comment: @JonSkeet  Okay. Thank you.  I was worried whether it will be okay to make it a separate question.  Thanks.

Comment: @ngen: Oh absolutely - take base64 out of the equation, and produce as complete a question as you can :) I'll try to take a look when I get a chance.

Comment: @JonSkeet  Unfortunately, The bug i believe is due to the Base64 itself, But that of PHP , I think. But i am not sure where to start debugging from. It **is** working  :

1) Android (Encrypt) - Android(Decrypt)  [I tried both with and without Base64 ] .

 2)Android(Encrypt)-PHP(Decrypt) 

 3) PHP ( Encrypt)  - PHP (Decrypt) 

 . However on doing PHP(Encrypt)-Android(Decrypt) => It's producing unwanted characters  prefixed to  the decrypted string

Comment: @ngen: Can you do PHP encrypt/base64-encode/base64-decode/decrypt?

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, all using Base Encoding. All combination works , Except Android(Decrypt) !.   Right now, I was trying out this:
(1) Base64'd the data 
(2) Encrypted it
(3) Base64'd encrypted string
(4) Passed it to android
(5) Base_Decoded ( Works Fine)
(6) Decrypted using Cipher. ( Mangled!!! Again! ). I can't Base_decode this data again since it's mangled. Is it due to the buggy bouncy castle?. Since i was just decrypting a Base64'd data  it wasn't due to the original string's encoding.

In short, Cipher.doFinal() is prefixing unwanted chars. But it's not doing it on Android-Encrypted data.

Comment: @ngen: That indicates that it isn't base64. You've got the same encrypted data on both sides (output of 2 and output of 5), but decryption fails.

Comment: @JonSkeet Exactly. That's what i wanted to convey. I understood that already. So the decrypting is failing but **only** on the data i'm encrypting from PHP. [Android->Android works] .  I'm using PHPSecLib BTW.   But if that library was buggy, PHP->PHP and Android->PHP   wouldn't work. Right?. Any ideas?

Comment: @ngen: It may well just be the way that you're configuring the keys.

Comment: @JonSkeet  I am not sure of that. If it was that case , then it wouldn't   decrypt the  encrypted string at all. Right?. It is decrypting  in my case. Full string is there!. Just that it's prefixed with a meaningless list of characters. :-( .

Comment: @ngen: Ah - in that case it may well just be the CBC/padding modes (or initialization vector etc) involved. You should investigate that.

Comment: !!!! @JonSkeet  , You saved me. 
 I did think about Padding , But i guess i became overly conscious about the encoding and how it was working the other way around. So i was playing around that alone.

`cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");` . And I'm done. :D . Sorry for all the trouble.

But still  i do not understand how all the other permutations were working except this one without forcing the PKCS1 .

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is one of sign.  The first sample 'the should' is treating the output bytes as 8-bit unsigned.  The Android version is treating them as signed bytes.

Is your code actually failing?

*Edit*

`cipher.final()` seems to be designed to finish decryption. Did you call `cipher.update()` first? See the example here, and look for `update(...)` stackoverflow.com/questions/3150830/android-encryption

Here's the [Android Cipher documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/Cipher.html), for your convenience.

Comment: Yes, It is failing when the 'signed' byte array goes to cipher decryption.

Comment: What input type does the decryption expect?  If it expects an array of unsigned, you may have to convert the byte array to an unsigned.

Comment: It's the Android's  `Cipher.doFinal(byte[])` .   It is expecting bytes . But it's failing to decrypt the data and is adding a lot of junk in front of the actual data.

Comment: I think it is Cipher.doFinal(byte[])

Comment: I'm totally confused about the bug , I'm sorry . I'll be more clear & specific.  Cipher.doFinal() accepts byte array and i'm trying it correctly, it's even decrypting. But the issue like i have mentioned in the edit is that, its producing  Illegible string . Which I'm assuming now  , is due to signed/unsigned bytes ?. Java supports only signed bytes?.

Comment: Wait, how did you encrypt the data to begin with?

Comment: RSA-SHA1 format . In PHP.  It's working from Android(Encrypt) => PHP(Decrypt).  But on the other direction , This is happening.   Lots of irrelevant characters are coming in the decrypted string.

Comment: `cipher.final()` seems to be designed to _finish_ decryption.  Did you call `cipher.update()` first?  See the example here, and look for `update(...)`  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150830/android-encryption

Comment: The way i understood  about Cipher's working is that it's multipart  . Update() for adding more bytes so that you can effectively continue decrypting part by part.   doFinal() does the same job , except that it finalizes Cipher's work.  Thanks for suggestion. But unfortunately  it's not the part that's causing the issue. :(.

`cipher.update(enc_bytes);
   byte[]  dt = cipher.doFinal();   
   String code=new String(dt,"UTF-8");
   System.out.println(code);`  I've tried this code. And no, it doesn't work. Still gives junk characters.

Comment: `doFinal(byte[] input) `
          Encrypts or decrypts data **in a single-part operation**, *or*   **finishes** a multiple-part operation.

Answer (score -2):

Try this on your byte array

```
byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
String string = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Absolutely not. Unless you have any evidence that this is *actually* meant to be UTF-8-encoded text (I see no such evidence in the question), you shouldn't be trying to create text out of it.

Comment: The answer is totally irrelevant.

Comment: My suggestion was based on the previous question at that particular time there was no code added which said that the data was being encrypted. There have been 2 edits to the question since I gave answers. I don't try creating text for the sake of creating it. People ought to read their code segments carefully before hitting the send button.