# Encrypt and Decrypt data with a key

Tags: java, android

I have 3-4 applications in android that sends messages to each other through broadcasts. I want that message to be secure. For that I want to encrypt the strings I am sending from one application and want to decrypt the message when other app receives the broadcast message. No other app should be able to decrypt it. Please tell me the best way to do it in Android.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150830/android-encryption

Answer (score 0):

I've followed this [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788018/android-encryption-decryption-with-aes) without problem, you just need to obtain byte[] from you string.

Answer (score 0):

> I have 3-4 applications in android that sends messages to each other through broadcasts. I want that message to be secure

Use signature-level custom permissions.

> For that I want to encrypt the strings I am sending from one application and want to decrypt the message when other app receives the broadcast message.

Encryption is pointless, as anyone with the technical ability to intercept your broadcasts will have the ability to reverse-engineer your app, get your encryption key, and decrypt the message.