# simple encryption algorithm for numbers

Tags: encryption

I'm working on a project that take the GPS location every 5 seconds and send it to the server, but i need to make a little of security, so i need to encrypt the location in android device and decrypt it in server side, so i'm searching for a simple algorithm to do this
Thanks in advance

Comment: Something like AES...

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150830/android-encryption)

Answer (score 0):

The ideas for you to try:

1. Send your data over HTTPS. It will add the layer of security you need and it's one of the simplest methods available.
2. Use [Java Encryption API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html) with asymmetric cryptographic algorithm like RSA. You should probably avoid using AES or similar symmetric algorithm because you should not store passphrase in your Android app - it could be quite easily compromised.