# Encrypted Android Database (SQLite?)

Tags: android, sqlite, encryption, sd-card

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android database encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203987/android-database-encryption)

I have a sensitive-ish SQLite database that I'd like to be able to store on the SDCard for more storage. Seems like there isn't a documented way to do this. Anyone have a method that works? Open to any ideas.

Thanks!

Comment: If it's that sensitive you should encrypt it on the internal memory too since getting at it on a rooted phone is trivial.