# Encrypt SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, security, encryption, sqlcipher

I have been searching for a while and got these results:

[Android database encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203987/android-database-encryption)

[encrypt sqlite database Android:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24576229/encrypt-sqlite-database-android)

[How to encrypt android sqlite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11383270/how-to-encrypt-android-sqlite-database)

They all suggest using SQLCipher, which is a valid solution, but the commercial license costs $499.

**(1)** Hasn't SQLite implemented any kind of security mechanism yet ?

**(2)** Do you know of cheaper alternatives ?

Thank you.

Comment: [SQLite Encryption Extension](http://www.sqlite.org/see/doc/trunk/www/readme.wiki)

Comment: @RickS Just found out this: `A perpetual source code license for the SQLite Encryption Extension (SEE) costs US $2000.00.` So it's not valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some mails, it turns out that SQLCipher has a **Community Edition** available, that can be used if agreed with the license.

[Here](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android/) is a guide on how to integrate and use it in Android.

[Here](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/open-source/) and [here](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/license/) licensing details.