# How can I encrypt sqlite in android using my own encryption library?

Tags: android, sqlite, encryption

I want my sqlite database encrypted with a particular algorithms (AES, TwoFish). It is ideal if I just can provide the name of the encryption method and the my database will be encrypted using that method. How can I do that?

Comment: check this link <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203987/android-database-encryption>