# Encryption on default Sqlite DB Android

Tags: android, sqlite, security

Does Android do an encryption to the sqlite database owned by the application ?

Reading the documentation and various forums I could only gather that the database is protected by the application owning it and it is not visible to the other apps .

Can this mean that it is a very viable security hole ? Why doesn't Android advice developers to encrypt the sqlite databases ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android does not encrypt sqlite databases (or any files created by the application, no matter their location). Files (including a database) created in internal storage are protected by uid, which means they cannot be easily read by other apps. However, if the device is rooted, they can be easily copied and/or read.

It's only insecure if you store data that shouldn't be stored there. Your options if you want a higher level of security are (a) to store encrypted data (b) use some other [encrypted database service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203987/android-database-encryption).

Comment: Does apple encrypt its core data ?

Comment: Core Data's default data stores are not encrypted. However, iOS does have an encrypted file system, which is unlocked when the user enters their passcode.