# how to encrypt database in android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, encryption

i developed an app in android wich use a database to save and load data at start. My question is: was it encrypt by default? if not, how can i encrypt my database file in order to make it more secure?

Comment: I assume that you are referring to an SQLite database, right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android database encryption](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203987/android-database-encryption)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> was it encrypt by default?

No.

> how can i encrypt my database file in order to make it more secure?

Use [SQLCipher for Android](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android/) and a user-supplied passphrase.

Comment: i don't understand how it works..can you help me please?

Comment: @xXJohnRamboXx: That is too broad for Stack Overflow. I have a whole book chapter on using SQLCipher for Android. You are welcome to review [these webinar slides](https://commonsware.com/webinars/sqlCipher) of mine, and there are probably other blog posts and online resources that you can find via a search engine. If you have a more specific concern, ask a fresh Stack Overflow question.