# Is it possible to encrypt the whole database in android?

Tags: android

Is it possible to encrypt the whole database? I'm currently using AES 256 ECB encryption for field level encryption. I need to know if there is any good option for encrypting the whole database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

> [SQLCipher](https://guardianproject.info/code/sqlcipher/) is an SQLite extension that provides transparent 256-bit AES
>   encryption of database files.

Source: [Android database encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203987/android-database-encryption)

Comment: The problem is that there isn't any easy way to integrate it with any ORM.

Answer (score 2):

You can also encrypt database with different available standard library.

we used below library it works very good..

One of them is : https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher

For Specific to Android : https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher

Comment: It turns out that this is the same project as https://guardianproject.info/code/sqlcipher, Guardian Project took Zetetic's SQLCipher and made SQLCipher for Android.  Zetetic now maintains both.